# How do i save this json as Plist in following format?

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, plist

Hi i have a JSON like following structure

```
{
   "taxi":[
      {
         "id":"173",
         "taxiName":"texi cabs",
         "taxiDescription":"test desc",
         "contactNumber":[
            {
               "Number":"vodafoen,4686565635"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"172",
         "taxiName":"Blue Moon",
         "taxiDescription":"test desc",
         "contactNumber":[
            {
               "Number":"vodafone,45686532"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"174",
         "taxiName":"yellow cabs",
         "taxiDescription":"test",
         "contactNumber":[
            {
               "Number":"airvoice,657865"
            },
            {
               "Number":"simmens,643437547457"
            },
            {
               "Number":"tescom,96831635365"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

[Link](http://zonewebs.org/website/naveen/test/tempjson/jsonTaxi.php)

From this iam trying to save the "contactNumber" of each element into a new plist. Please help me.

So the final plist look slike 
Contact list of all these 3 elements

I have tried this

```
   paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *taxiPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"taxicontactlist.plist"];
    NSMutableArray *newList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    taxiContactRoot=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    taxiContactNewArray=taxiContactRoot[@"taxi"];
    taxiContact=[taxiContactNewArray valueForKey:@"contactNumber"] ;
    NSArray *s=[[NSArray alloc]init];
    s=[taxiContact valueForKey:@"Number"];
    //taxiContact=[taxiContact valueForKey:@"Number"];
    NSString *str;
    for(int i=0;i<[taxiContact count];i++){
        str=[s objectAtIndex:i];
        [newList addObject:str];
        str=@"";
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",newList);
   [newList writeToFile:taxiPath atomically:YES];
```

but the result is

[image]

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Read the JSON into an `NSDictionary` (`NSJSONSerialization`). Then get the `taxi` `NSArray`. Then get the contacts:

```
NSArray *contactNumbers = [taxiArray valueForKey:@"contactNumber"];
```

save this array to generate the plist (on disk).

---

Depending on the way you want to extract the contacts (and their sub-information) you may want to look at using key paths and [collection operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html) (such as `@unionOfArrays`).

Comment: Do you actually have any JSON or is your data above a log of an `NSDictionary`?

Comment: i have  json  ,check that link

Comment: So you're loading from a plist on disk for testing?

Comment: iam loading from a link,and trying to save it as plist of a good structure.

Comment: I haven't tried 2 levels before, but try `NSArray *numbers = [taxiContactNewArray valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.contactNumber.@unionOfArrays.Number"];`